# Can an Activity input profile "remember" details from the previous Activity submitted?

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, profile, activities, relationships

Newbie here, powered by CiviCRM 4.7.28 on WordPress.  The closest prior thread I could find is [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19508/what-are-some-ways-to-handle-flight-information).

The use case is high school students self-reporting classes completed and corresponding grades.  I thought of attaching a multiple record fieldset to a student - school relationship, but alas that's [not supported](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/creating-custom-fields/#multiple-record-fieldsets).  Besides, profiles don't expose relationships and I'm too green to jump to Webforms+Drupal or Caldera Forms.

So open to suggestions, but the workaround driving this question is treating each course completion as a discrete activity that ties the student, the school, and the course info.  What I don't grasp how to do is having the 2nd thru N submissions remember the student and school so they don't have to keep re-keying this info on each course submission.  Typically they'll submit 4 to 6 course results in one sitting.

Comment: I know you feel too green to tackle Webforms or Caldera Forms - but the time you spend learning them will pay off in short order if you need to make forms like the ones you describe!

Comment: Was hoping to stay focused on the CiviCRM learning curve, looks like I'll have to detour   Initial impression is that Webforms can handle custom fields. Not sure about Civi+Caldera though, the list of Processors seems very field-specific.

Comment: Think of it more as a short-cut than a detour!  There is a lot more experience around here using webforms (Drupal) with Civi than Caldera (WordPress) which is newer (but quite active).

Comment: I couldn't get Caldera to work and am hip-deep in Drupal+Webform right now.  It's looking good.  Thanks to both for the advice and encouragement!